# Query to get parent where all the children have a certain value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables, PARENT and CHILD where CHILD has fk from PARENT.

**PARENT**

```
p_id|name|address
1   |Aaaa|AddressA
2   |Bbbb|AddressB
3   |Cccc|AddressC
```

**CHILD**

```
c_id|name|category|p_id
11  |Zzzz|Test1   |1
12  |Yyyy|Test2   |1
13  |Xyxy|Test1   |1
14  |Wwww|Test1   |2
15  |Vvvv|Test1   |2
16  |Uuuu|Test1   |2
17  |Tttt|Test2   |3
18  |Ssss|Test3   |3
19  |Rrrr|Test2   |3
20  |Qqqq|Test2   |3
```

I'm trying to get PARENT where all CHILD.category = 'Test1' with this query

```
select distinct p.* from PARENT p join CHILD c
    on p.p_id = c.p_id
    where c.category = 'Test1';
```

Expected result, because all of CHILD with p_id 2 has category with value 'Test1':

```
p_id|name|address
2   |Bbbb|AddressB
```

But I got this because it returns PARENT where CHILD has category = 'Test1':

```
p_id|name|address
1   |Aaaa|AddressA
2   |Bbbb|AddressB
```

Can anyone help to point out where I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is on the right track in getting the results, it just needs a further filter to see there are no other records other than Test1 for the records you selected from CHILD.

We can do that using a NOT EXISTS condition

```
 select distinct p.* 
  from PARENT p 
   join CHILD c1
     on p.p_id = c1.p_id
  where c1.category = 'Test1'
    and not exists(select c2.id
                     from CHILD c2
                    where c2.p_id=c1.p_id 
                      and c2.category <> 'Test1')
```

Comment: I have corrected it now. The alias was set incorrectly for the first CHILD

Comment: yeaha that i knew it that it wil be for first CHILD  but howcum the answwer got accepted?? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may use a CTE to first get those child ids with only `Test1` and then join it with parent.

```
WITH c 
     AS (SELECT p_id 
         FROM   child 
         GROUP  BY p_id 
         HAVING MAX(category) = MIN(category) 
                AND MAX(category) = 'Test1') 
SELECT p.* 
FROM   parent p 
       JOIN c 
         ON p.p_id = c.p_id;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=db3994e58ffd4338ec682a606874e786)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct p.* 
  FROM PARENT p 
  JOIN CHILD c
    ON p.p_id = c.p_id
 WHERE c.category = 'Test1'
   AND p.p_id = 2;
```

This should return what you want.
'Aaaa' satisfy all condition in your query. So, it is returned as part of result. If you want to have the result only for p_id = 2 you should have it as one of WHERE condition.